# MySql – Query to get contextual results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a nice little brain teaser and really hope someone can help me. 
I have the following table:

> ID ------------------- Relevance
>   1 -------------------- 2,3,4,5,7
>   2 -------------------- 1,3,5,7,9
>   3 -------------------- 1,2,4,5,6

What I would like to do is write a query to order the results by the rows that provide the highest relevance to my input list:

> 1,5,6

So order by the row that offers the most matches from the list and from the relevance column. Row ID 3 has the most matches, with 1,5 and 6. Row ID 2 has only 2 matches whereas Row ID 1 only has 1 match - so in the above example, the answer would be: 
ROW ID's in order of relevance

> ID
>   3
>   2
>   1

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a FULLTEXT index on the relevance column, and use the MATCH function.

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable WHERE MATCH (relevante) AGAINST ('1 5 6');
```

note that I'm separating the terms using a blank space. I believe using commas could be interpreted as looking for the exact string "1,5,6".

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, keep getting an error "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list". But just to clarity, I would like to order by column with most results that match first

Comment: I fixed error as above, but returns 0 results. in the above example I would still like to return all 3 rows, but in order of most matches first, thus ROW: 3.2.1 - hope this helps to clarify